# How to use length of response data to display buttons conditionally - React

Tags: reactjs, button, conditional-statements, rendering, response

I am trying to use the length of response array for displaying buttons conditionally. I am able to get the length and display it inside paragraph tag as below. But while checking if index > {numRows}, it isn't setting the value. Tried converting to integer like "index > Number.parseInt({numRows})" thinking it could be a string but still did not work.

```
render() {
const toRender = this.state.Items.filter((i) => i.itemNo);
const numRows = toRender.length;

return (
  <div>
    {Items.map((element, index) => (
      <div className="form-inline" key={index}>
        <p>Number of rows = {numRows}</p>     // Could see the output here

        <Grid item>
          {index > numRows ? (     // problem here, value not getting set for 'numRows'
            <button type="button" onClick={() => this.add(index)}>
              Add
            </button>
          ) : null}
        </Grid>
      </div>
    ))}
  </div>
);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because the code you wrote here is wrong, This may work

```
 render() {
    const toRender = this.state.Items.filter((i) => i.itemNo);
    const numRows = toRender.length;

    return (
      <div>
        {Items.map((element, index) => (
          <div className="form-inline" key={index}>
            <p>Number of rows = {numRows}</p>

            <Grid item>
              {index > numRows ? (
                <button type="button" onClick={() => this.add(index)}>
                  Add
                </button>
              ) : null}
            </Grid>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Comment: I have not posted the correct code here, my mistake. I tried using numRows instead of {numRows} already but that did not help. If I substitute number like say "10" instead of numRows in the code, the code works as expected. So the problem is with the value not getting set for numRows.

Comment: Then I'll need value of Items state I think the filter function you have applied is not working

Comment: I realized the problem was not because of numRows. The code wasn't working since 'index' kept getting incremented every time I added a new row through UI, which is why my condition never met and did not work as expected. Modifying this line "index + 1  > numRows", solved my problem. Thank you for trying to help.